# Execute javascript on my website through linux server (node, socket.io)

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have website with games in html5/JS. I want make it looks like there are many users playing to promote it faster. Results of games are presented in real time with websockets socket.io

So im writing bots that are imitating  players on my linux servers, everything is ok, results are in database but most important thing don't work. Displaying live results to other users through javascript. Server of websockets running on node js server so its user JS <--> server JS communication.

I don't know how to bite this problem:

1. **execute somehow website locally through node JS which is responsible for sending live result?** (tryed that, node dont undertstand html and JS + HTML is used in process of communication with node JS live results server)
2. **execute my website with some kind of linux browser emulator with JS** (that would be easiest, don't need to use bots then, only couple instances of this browser emulator. Something like this exist?
3. **Communicate php <--> node socket.io server?** (im reading currently about this, maybe someone know < php 5.3 [without namespace] version of software like this?)